# Group multiple ansible tasks under a single conditional

Tags: if-statement, solr, task, conditional-statements, ansible

I am using [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) as a system orchestration tool. First of all, let me describe my eventual goal.

I want to create a playbook or two that will go grab [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) from the web, set itself up, and then start an index based on some configuration. If any of this so far sounds suspect, please stop me here.

Now, I don't want to grab the [solr tarball](http://apache.cs.utah.edu/lucene/solr/5.4.0/) if I don't have to, so I've currently got a task/play that looks like this.

```
- stat: path="path to solr home/solr/bin/init script"
  register: solr_script

- name: getting solr
  when: solr_script.stat.exists == False
  shell: mkdir -p "path to download dir"
  get_url: url="download url" dest= "path to download dir"
  shell: tar zxvf "path to download dir/tgz file" -C "path to solr home"
  shell: rm -rf "path to download dir"

- name: start solr
  shell: "path to solr home/solr/bin/solr init script" start
  sudo: yes
```

I attempting to check if the solr init script has already been downloaded before going and grabbing it.

When I ran this script as is, I get the error,

```
multiple actions specified in task: 'shell' and 'getting solr'
```

That seems reasonable-ish, maybe the formatting is wrong? I tried this

```
- name: getting solr
  when: solr_script.stat.exists == False
      shell: mkdir -p "path to download dir"
      get_url: url="download url" dest= "path to download dir"
      shell: tar zxvf "path to download dir/tgz file" -C "path to solr home"
      shell: rm -rf "path to download dir"
```

Got a syntax error.

On the ansible documentation page, I see this bit of information.

```
Note that if you have several tasks that all share the same conditional statement, you can affix the conditional to a task include statement as below. All the tasks get evaluated, but the conditional is applied to each and every task:
```

That seems to be getting to what I need.

But then they follow up with this example.

```
- include: tasks/sometasks.yml
  when: "'reticulating splines' in output"
```

I don't really understand the "include", and the example doesn't seem to illustrate what I want. So, if my initial assumptions are correct and this is indeed how I would want to go about getting solr, how would I write up an ansible task that will conditionally execute a group of tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
- name: getting solr
  when: solr_script.stat.exists == False
  shell: mkdir -p "path to download dir"
  get_url: url="download url" dest= "path to download dir"
  shell: tar zxvf "path to download dir/tgz file" -C "path to solr home"
  shell: rm -rf "path to download dir"
```

A task consists of a name (optional), one task/module, and modifiers like `when`, `with`, etc.  You can't have more than one task (in this case `shell` & `get_url`) in a task.  So you'll need to break this down into multiple tasks:

```
- name: make solr directory
  file: path=/path/to/download/dir"
        state=directory

- name: download solr
  get_url: url=<url> dest=/path/to/download/dir

- name: unpack solr
  shell: tar xvzf ...
```

And so on...

To conditionally perform a series of tasks you can do a number of things:

1. You can use the `include` statement as you mentioned in your question, which will let you apply a conditional to all the tasks within that include file.
2. You can create a role that performs all the tasks and again use a conditional to invoke it (or just apply the role to the hosts, etc. that you desire to have the role applied to)
3. You can add `when` clauses to each of your tasks individually.
4. You can use parameters for the `shell` and other modules like `creates` or `removes` which will look for the presence or absence of a file with which to determine whether or not to perform a task.

Comment: thanks for the kindly advice. I basically ended up just sticking the same "when" clause on all of my tasks, which felt hacky, but ended up working. I did not know about create/removes though, that seems to do what I want without the additional check to see if the file exists. Accepting your answer, your list should be able to help others.

Answer (score 20):

In Ansible 2.0 it's possible like this:

```
- block:
    - shell: mkdir -p "path to download dir"
    - get_url: url="download url" dest= "path to download dir"
    - shell: tar zxvf "path to download dir/tgz file" -C "path to solr home"
    - shell: rm -rf "path to download dir"
  when: solr_script.stat.exists == False
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is possible with ansible<=1.9, using include

Answer (score 0):

For ansible 2.x use the other accepted answer. You can use ansible 1.9.x to do this using the `include` statement.

First create two `.yml` files for this, `main.yml` and `solr.yml` in your current role directory.

Your `main.yml` should look like:

```
- stat: path="path to solr home/solr/bin/init script"
  register: solr_script

- include: solr.yml
  when: solr_script.stat.exists == False
```

In `solr.yml` file have all the tasks you want to run for the include condition in your `main.yml`:

```
- shell: mkdir -p "path to download dir"
- get_url: url="download url" dest= "path to download dir"
- shell: tar zxvf "path to download dir/tgz file" -C "path to solr home"
- shell: rm -rf "path to download dir"
```

More on [include statements](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html). Hope that makes sense, Cheers!